# XML: can't have multiple elements with provided schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm kinda new to XML and learning XML Schema right now. I've encountered problem where I cannot create more than one `car` element with provided xml schema.

Right now I have a simple schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.cars.lt"
            xmlns="http://www.cars.lt"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            xmlns:carsType="http://www.cars.lt">

  <xs:element name="cars" type="carsType:CarType">
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name ="CarType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="car" type="carsType:CarWithBrandAndModel">
        <xs:key name="carKey">
          <xs:selector xpath="car"/>
          <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="NoCarsRef" refer="carKey">
                    <xs:selector xpath="noCar" />
                    <xs:field xpath="@id" />
                </xs:keyref>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

This schema generates only one car element when instead I need to have more than one.

And when I'm trying to create two `<car>` elements it gives me an error that element `cars` has invalid child element `car` in namespace `http://www.cars.lt`.

What I tried was inserting CarType complex type into `cars` element, but it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The default for `maxOccurs` is `1`.  If you want your XSD to allow multiple `car` elements, add `maxOccurs` with a value greater than `1` or `unbounded`:

```
<xs:element name="car" type="carsType:CarWithBrandAndModel" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```